# Can a sequence cover all the real numbers in $(0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Or even more generally, can a real sequence $(a_n)_n$ cover a whole interval $(a,b)$? By covering I mean, $\forall x \in (a,b), \exists n \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $a_n=x$.

I think the answer is that there cannot be such a sequence, but I cannot prove or disprove this. Does the result directly follow from the fact that any real interval is uncountable but the sequences are indexed on a countable set $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes, ît’s an immediate consequence of that fact.

Comment: There is also the somewhat-related interesting fact that you can write a sequence whose set of limit points is $[0,1]$, but no such sequence exists for the interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Formally, a sequence (of members of $\Bbb R$) is a function $\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$. Since $|\Bbb N| = \aleph_0 < c = | \Bbb R|$, then no sequence can enumerate all of the members of $\Bbb R$ (rather, the function in question can never be surjective).

Of course, you can see how this applies to the interval $(0,1)$ since $|(0,1)| = |\Bbb R|$.

Interestingly, in topology, there is a related notion called a "[net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))" which is like a generalization of a sequence, where the domain of the function need not be $\Bbb N$, just any [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) with a [preorder relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) on it. I suggest checking the links for formal definitions, but, intuitively, you can already see how it works.

In that context, your net could be, say, a function $f : (0,1) \to (0,1)$, e.g. $x \mapsto x$, or a function $f : \Bbb R \to (0,1)$, e.g. $x \mapsto 1/(1+e^x)$ -- whatever set you wish to use as your indexing set for your net.